# Finding transition probability in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For a homogeneous Markov chain on a finite state space $X$ with probability transition matrix $P$ and initial distribution $\mu$, what is the value of

$$P(\omega_n = x^{1} \mid \omega_0 = x^2, \omega_{2n} = x^{3}), $$

where $x^1, x^2, x^3 \in X$?

---

I am aware of the Markov property, so I think I can rewrite  it as

$$P(\omega_n = x^{1} \mid \omega_0 = x^{2}) $$

because the future states don't matter. Then I guess the answer is just $\mu p^{(n)}_{x^2, x^1}$? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect.  If you know you end up at $x_3$ it absolutely can affect the prob distribution of where you were in the past.  The Markov property said, conditioned on a past state, then **further-distant past** does not matter.  It never said that the **future** does not matter.

In your example, suppose $x_2$ can reach $x_1$ and $x_3$, but $x_1$ cannot reach $x_3$.  Then conditioning on a future at $x_3$, the prob of being at $x_1$ is $0$ (since you couldn't have reached $x_3$ from $x_1$).

To actually solve your problem, here's a hint: use the definition of conditional prob $P(A \mid B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$.  In fact, use it multiple times.

Can you finish from here?